# Нарезка страницы на блоки

Tags: веб-дизайн, php, html, css

В процессе изучения php.
Стала учиться нарезать страницу на блоки для того, чтобы эти блоки сохранять в отдельные файлы и потом подключать в нужных местах.
Все отлично, все нарезается, подключаются, код работает.
И вот проблема: при нарезке образуются "пустые строки". Т.е., добавляю код, например, от статус-бара, в отдельный файл, потом "подцепляю" его через include и в итоге при загрузке страницы в браузере сверху статус бара образуется пустая строка, так, будто использовался тег <td>. Хотя на самом деле он не использовался. При чем в окне дизайна этой строки не видно. Все стоит на своих местах. Но при загрузке в браузере такая строка появляется (как говорится, "...на лыжах"...:((( ).
И собственно вопрос: как устранить эту проблему?
В гугле поюзала, что-то ничего подходящего не нашла. Только на вас вся надежда, профессионалы:)

Comment: Ошибок в HTML нет? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Елена покажи код, наверное divы какие-то не закрыты...

Comment: @Андрей Аршинов, @IntegralAL да вроде не выдает мне компилятор синтаксических ошибок. код ниже добавила.

Comment: я вообще пользуюсь dreamweaver cs6. В нем и любой код удобно редактировать (php,html,css,js) и визуально видно хорошо, что получается. может мне другой редактор попробовать использовать?

Comment: Сейчас установила Notepad++. То же самое.
Что не так? Не пойму. Ничего лишнего не добавляю. Ничего нужно (закрывающих тегов) не забываю. Все делаю, как в инструкции. Но стоит начать резать, все, сразу пустые строки появляются. Причем в любых шаблонах, в каких бы я нарезку ни делала.

Comment: Может быть какую-то настройку нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="это типа для компаии" />
<meta name="description" content="Выполняем весь спектр работ, занимаемся производством и поставками оборудования." />
<meta name="author" content="Корпорация СУПЕР-пупер" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<title>ТОО Корпорация СУПЕР-пупер</title>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Style" href="css/style.css">
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Style" href="css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myriadpro.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h5');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script></head>

<body>
<div id="status-bar">
<div id="status-bar-content">
<form action="#search" method="post" id="search-form">
<p>
<input type="text" name="query" value="Поиск" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search!" />
</p>
</form>
<div id="status-bar-commands">
<p id="welcome">Добро пожаловать!</p>
<p id="action-bar">
<a href="#kaz" title="kaz">Казакша</a>
<a href="#rus" title="rus">Русский</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content-top-shadow"></div>

<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs">

        <li id="home" class="current">
        <a href="#home" title="home">Главная</a>
        </li>

        <li id="products">
        <a href="#products" title="products">Продукция</a>
        </li>

        <li id="services">
        <a href="#services" title="services">Услуги</a>
        </li>

        <li id="about">
        <a href="#about" title="about">О нас</a>
        </li>

        <li id="contact">
        <a href="#contact" title="contact">Контакты</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

<div id="page-wrapper">

<div id="slideshow">

<div id="slides">
<a href="#products.work1" title="see details" class="thumb default-slide">
<img src="img/1.png" alt="Оборудование №1" class="slideshow-image" />    </a>

<a href="#products.work2" title="see details" class="thumb">
<img src="img/2.png" alt="Оборудование №2" class="slideshow-image" />    </a>

<a href="#products.work3" title="see details" class="thumb">
<img src="img/3.png" alt="Оборудование №3" class="slideshow-image" />    </a>    </div>

<div id="slideshow-commands">
<a href="#previous" title="предыдущая" id="previous-slide">&lt;</a>
<a href="#next" title="следующая" id="next-slide">&gt;</a>
<h4>
<a href="#products.work1" title="see details" id="slide-title">
КСО - 292    </a>    </h4>

</div>
</div>

<div id="message">
<h3>Мы гарантируем качество и
надежность нашей продукции!</h3>
<p>
Предоставление всего спектра работ – это наша основная специализация.
</p>
<p id="contact-info">
<span id="phone">8(0000) 00-00-00</span>
<span id="address">
г. Город,<br>
ул. Улица, 508/2
</span>
</p>
</div>

</div>

<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">

<div class="module" id="blog">

<h4 class="module-header-bar">Новости</h4>

<div class="blog-entry">
<h5><a href="#blogentry1" title="news1">Новостное сообщеие нашего предприятия под номером один.</a></h5>
<blockquote class="content"><p>
У нас появилась новость номер один. Здесь мы размещаем о новости анонс.
Чтобы перейти к прочтению новости - нужно кликнуть на ее названии. </p>
</blockquote>
<p class="meta">05.05.2013</p>
</div>

<div class="blog-entry">
<h5><a href="#blogentry2" title="news2">Новостное сообщеие нашего предприятия номер два.</a></h5>
<blockquote class="content">
<p>В результате откроется страница, на которой можно прочитать подробности именно к этой новости.</p>
</blockquote>
<p class="meta">05.05.2013</p>
</div>

<p id="read-more-wrapper">
<a href="#news" title="read more">
Читать все новости &gt;&gt;&gt; </a>    </p>
</div>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">

<div class="module" id="partners">

<h4 class="module-header-bar">Партнеры</h4>

<div class="partners-entry">
<blockquote class="content">
<p>Мы строим свои отношения с каждым заказчиком на основе индивидуального подхода,
открыты для взаимовыгодного сотрудничества,
готовы к долгосрочной совместной деятельности.</p>
</blockquote>
</div>

<p id="read-more-wrapper1">
<a href="#partners" title="read more">
Далее &gt;&gt;&gt; </a> </p>
</div>

<div class="module" id="docs">

<h4 class="module-header-bar">Документация</h4>

<div class="docs-entry">
<blockquote class="content">
<p>Техническая документация</p>
</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="docs-entry">
<blockquote class="content">
<p>Организационные документы</p>
</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="docs-entry">
<blockquote class="content">
<p>Сертификаты и награды</p>
</blockquote>
</div>

</div>
    </td>

    <td valign="top">
<div class="module" id="projects">

<h4 class="module-header-bar">Проекты</h4>

<div class="projects-entry">
<h5><a href="#project1" title="project1">Наш проект номер один.</a></h5>
<blockquote class="content">
<p>
Мы выполняем проекты различной сложности и направленности.</p>
</blockquote>
<p class="meta">05.05.2013</p>
</div>

<div class="projects-entry">
<h5><a href="#project2" title="project2">Наш проект номер два.</a></h5>
<blockquote class="content">
<p>
Если вы желаете узнать подробности о проекте, то кликните по его названию.</p>
</blockquote>
<p class="meta">05.05.2013</p>
</div>

<div class="projects-entry">
<h5><a href="#project3" title="project3">Наш проект номер три.</a></h5>
<blockquote class="content">
<p>Перед вами откроектся страница с подробной информацией.</p>
</blockquote>
<p class="meta">05.05.2013</p>
</div>

<p id="read-more-wrapper3">
<a href="#projects" title="read more">
Все проекты &gt;&gt;&gt; </a>   </p>
</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<div id="content-bottom-shadow"></div>

<div id="footer">
<p id="footer-text1"> 
<a href="#www.com/mail">Написать нам</a> | <a href="#www.com/faq">FAQ </a>| <a href="www.com/support">Техническая поддержка</a>
</p>
<p id="footer-text2">Copyright © 2013 ТОО «Корпорация СУПЕР-пупер»</p>
<div id="footer-image"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: вот это все нарезаю и получаю пустые строки. докопалась до того, что это проблема с кодировкой. меняю ее на utf8 без BOM, тогда пустые строки уходят, но появляются каракули. ужасьььььььььь. что же делать посоветуете?

Comment: попробуйте дописать DefaultCharset UTF-8 в файл .htaccess

Comment: УРА!УРА!УРА! Благодарю! Все получилось!:)